# de acesso na plataforma Moodle versão 3.10.1

Tags: moodle

I need help, error presented
cache/Invalid cache configuration file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the cache?

`$ php /your/moodle/path/admin/cli/purge_caches.php`